# Jquery Plugin for animating numbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making an ajax call to the server and then updating some stats. I want a plugin which animates the numbers.

e.g. initial value = 65
value after ajax call = 98

in a span of 2 seconds, the value displayed increases from 65 to 98 and the user is able to see that - like the digital speedometers or tachometers.

My search has not led me to find a plugin for this. Does anybody know of such plugin?

Comment: Wow, three implementations...Gimme some time and let me try them out and see if that is what I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesnt have a duration, but it's kinda close.  I'm not sure how to integrate a duration at the moment, and had to throw this together rather quickly.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.animateNumber = function(to) {
        var $ele = $(this),
            num = parseInt($ele.html()),
            up = to > num,
            num_interval = Math.abs(num - to) / 90;

        var loop = function() {
            num = Math.floor(up ? num+num_interval: num-num_interval);
            if ( (up && num > to) || (!up && num < to) ) {
                num = to;
                clearInterval(animation)
            }
            $ele.html(num);
        }

        var animation = setInterval(loop, 5);
    }
})(jQuery)

var $counter = $("#counter");
$counter.animateNumber(800);
```

```
<span id="counter">100</span>
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's one potential solution using jQuery's animate(), implemented as a function. The "duration" and "easing" arguments are optional.

```
function animateNumber($input, num, duration, easing)
{
    $input
        .data("start", parseInt($input.val()))
        .animate({"val":parseInt(num)},
        {
            easing: easing == undefined ? "linear" : easing,
            duration: duration == undefined ? 500 : parseInt(duration),
            step: function(fin,obj)
            {
                var $this = jQuery(this);
                var start = parseInt($this.data("start"));
                $this.val(parseInt((fin-start)*obj.state) + start ); 
            }
        });
}

// Usage
animateNumber($("#my_input_box"), 23);
animateNumber($("#my_input_box"), 23, 1500, "swing"); // 1.5 sec, swing easing
```

Answer (score 2):

Simshaun's code works perfectly, except in the case where the number to animate to is less than the current value; leading to an infinite loop of numeric flooring.

Here's the updated code,

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.animateNumber = function(to) {
        var $ele = $(this),
            num = parseInt($ele.html()),
            up = to > num,
            num_interval = Math.abs(num - to) / 90;

        var loop = function() {
            num = up ? Math.ceil(num+num_interval) : Math.floor(num-num_interval);
            if ( (up && num > to) || (!up && num < to) ) {
                num = to;
                clearInterval(animation)
            }
            $ele.html(num);
        }

        var animation = setInterval(loop, 5);
    }
})(jQuery)

var $counter = $("#counter");
$counter.animateNumber(800);
```

```
<span id="counter">100</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jquery plugin that allows you to animate numbers:

https://github.com/kajic/jquery-animateNumber

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a jQuery plugin for doing a "picker style" animation on numbers using CSS3 transforms and transitions.  A blog post describing it with working examples is available [here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2012/09/picker-style-number-animation-with-jquery-and-css3/).  The code is also available on github and can be downloaded [here](https://raw.github.com/MarkRhodes/number-animation/master/numberAnimate.js).