# jquery animate number

Tags: jquery, numbers, jquery-animate, easing

I am trying to animate a number value, this scenario from actionscript 3:

```
import caurina.transitions.*;

var p1:Point = new Point();
var t:Number =1;
var xv:int=500;
var yv:int=300;

Tweener.addTween(p1, {time: t, x: xv, y: yv, transition: "easeOutElastic", onUpdate:reportPosition });

function reportPosition(){trace(p1);}
```

I found this topic, and it works excellent:

[Jquery Plugin for animating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034819/jquery-plugin-for-animating-numbers)

However it doesnt have easing property, which changes the scenario quite drastic.

With 'easeOut' when value is animated, it goes over the top and comes back.

Is this possible to achieve this effect?

Comment: This type of easing: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html & http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#easing?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jquery plugin with which you can animate numbers and use any jqueryui easing (you need to get the easing yourself from jqueryui.com):

https://github.com/kajic/jquery-animateNumber